# Flutter keyboard dismissed when showing alertDialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a text field in my Flutter app where a user can enter their name. They can press "submit". But when a name is too short, I show a dialog.

The problem: when the dialog is shown the keyboard gets automatically dismissed and the alert dialog jumps from above (when the keyboard is still active) to below (when the keyboard isn't active anymore, half a second later).

```
                        showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
                                  title: Text("Error"),
                                  content:
                                      Text("Name too short"),
                                ));
```

Is it possible to keep the keyboard active when showing an AlertDialog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do what you want to do but I have kinda figured out hack try it out and see what you think

```
Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              onFieldSubmitted: (String value) async {
                if (value.length < 3) {
                  return await showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                      title: Text("Error"),
                      content: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          AbsorbPointer(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              cursorColor: Colors.white,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: " Name too short",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                              autofocus: true,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes indeed it works, but it's a bit hacky. I'm going to wait if there are other answers that are less hacky. Otherwise, I will accept it! Thanks!

Comment: no problem i realize it is a hack but there is no native way to keep keyboard open with alert dialog you could create your own dialog class but that would be a lot of work just to stop the keyboard from closing. I understand if you want to wait

Comment: did you ever find a better answer to this

Comment: upvote please that way other people can find it easier i upvoted your post :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way:

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
         SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.show');
         return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Error"),
            content: Text("Name too short"),
         );
     },
);
```